# NSUserActivity webpageURL becoming nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a universal link, say: `https://universallink.com/account/settings`

When my application is fully closed, this works perfectly.  However, if app is open in background and the link is clicked from safari or from slack, or something like that, this is non functional.

What I have observed:

1. `application(\_:willContinueUserActivityWithType:)` is of type "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb"
2. `application.userActivity` **is** `nil` OR `application.userActivity` **not** `nil` but `application.userActivity.webpageURL` **is** `nil` during `application(\_:willContinueUserActivityWithType:)`
3. `application(\_:continue:restorationHandler:)` is never called.
4. `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` are returning true.
5. Checking for `let url = launchOptions?[.url] as? URL` in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` finds nothing.

I am not exactly sure how to proceed in fixing this scenario. The user activity clearly knows that is was opened with a link, but the link is never preserved so as to be handled.

Does anyone know something else that may be causing this issue?

Comment: @daredevuk1234 did you find the solution? I am facing this issue.

Comment: @venky i wish i could remember - i definitely fixed it and it ended up being a pretty trivial solve, but I can't honestly recall what I did

Comment: just took a lot of research and then I found some stray thread that helped me solve it